# Image detector website

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for online image recognition website.

How it works is when I submit a photograph to the website, the website will tell me information about the photo. For example:

```
This photo is Mona Lisa painting. Painted by Leonardo Da Vinci.
```

Have you found some website like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know two websites that try to match the image you supply with others that are found in the web, then you can visit the results' sites and find more info.

- [TinEye](http://www.tineye.com/)
- [GazoPa](http://www.gazopa.com/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [Google Images](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/searchbyimage.html) for this.

**Search by Image**

> Now you can explore the web in an entirely new way by beginning your
>   Google search with an image. Learn more about images on the web and
>   your own photos.